# OpenGL line rasterization with integer endpoints

Tags: opengl

In the OpenGL specification, line rasterization is defined by the 'diamond-exit' rule.

> For each fragment f with center at window coordinates x<sub>f</sub> and y<sub>f</sub>,
> define a diamond-shaped region that is the intersection of four half planes:
>
> R<sub>f</sub> = {(x, y) | |x−x<sub>f</sub>| + |y−y<sub>f</sub>| < 1/2}.
>
> Essentially, a line segment starting at p<sub>a</sub> and ending at p<sub>b</sub> produces those fragments f for which the segment intersects R<sub>f</sub>, except if p<sub>b</sub> is contained in R<sub>f</sub>.
>
> (from the OpenGL 1.5 [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec15.pdf), section 3.4.1)

This means that a line parallel to the x or y axis with integer endpoints will not be drawn at all. E.g. a line starting at (x,y) = (5, 5) and ending at (5,10) will never have  a manhattan distance smaller than 1/2 to any fragment center.

Is there any reason why the spec left such a "hole" between two fragments?

In the following part an additional criterion is described to determine if a fragment is drawn:

> To avoid difficulties when an endpoint lies on a boundary of R<sub>f</sub> we (in principle) perturb the supplied endpoints by a tiny amount. Let p<sub>a</sub> and p<sub>b</sub> have window coordinates (x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>) and (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>), respectively. Obtain the perturbed endpoints p′<sub>a</sub> given by (x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>) − (ϵ, ϵ<sup>2</sup>) and p′<sub>b</sub> given by (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>) − (ϵ, ϵ<sup>2</sup>). Rasterizing the line segment starting at p<sub>a</sub> and ending at p<sub>b</sub> produces those fragments f for which the segment starting at p′<sub>a</sub> and ending on p′<sub>b</sub> intersects R<sub>f</sub>, except if p′<sub>b</sub> is contained in R<sub>f</sub>. ϵ is chosen to be so small that rasterizing the line segment produces the same fragments when δ is substituted for ϵ for any 0 < δ ≤ ϵ.
>
> (from the OpenGL 1.5 [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec15.pdf), section 3.4.1)

I assume they have added this extra rule to account for edge cases like my example. But why didn't they allow points with a distance of exactly 1/2 in the first place?

Also, since δ and ϵ are positive, does this mean that lines that pass perfectly in the middle between two fragment centers will default to the lower fragment (with a horizontal line) or the leftmost fragment (with a vertical line)?

Comment: In case of <= 1/2, wouldn't then in the edge case you describe lines be drawn with two pixel width?

Comment: @BDL Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why didn't they allow points with a distance of exactly 1/2 in the first place?

Because that would result in generating two fragments in these cases, resulting in a thicker line than intended. One needs some kind of *tie-breaking* rule, and the formulation chosen in the GL spec is just that.

> Also, since δ and ϵ are positive, does this mean that lines that pass perfectly in the middle between two fragment centers will default to the lower fragment (with a horizontal line) or the leftmost fragment (with a vertical line)?

No. Because the GL spec doesn't require implementations to use the diamond exit rule. The paragraph you quoted from actually begins with

> Ideally, the GL uses a “diamond-exit" rule to determine those fragments that
>   are produced by rasterizing a line segment. [...]

In later paragraphs it is stated:

> Because the initial and final conditions of the diamond-exit rule may be difficult
>   to implement, other line segment rasterization algorithms are allowed, subject to
>   the following rules:
>
> 1. The coordinates of a fragment produced by the algorithm may not deviate by
>      more than one unit in either x or y window coordinates from a corresponding
>      fragment produced by the diamond-exit rule.
> 2. The total number of fragments produced by the algorithm may differ from
>      that produced by the diamond-exit rule by no more than one.
>
> [...]

Rule 1 alone already allows an implementation to use some tie-breaking rule of it's own choosing.

Comment: How would an end-user be able to determine what type of tie-breaking rule is implemented? This information is crucial for developers who want to use pixel-perfect graphics.

Comment: You can't. OpenGL never guaranteed pixel-perfect graphics.

Comment: Btw, that is directly stated in Appendix A: "The OpenGL specification is not pixel exact. It therefore does not guarantee an exact match between images produced by different GL implementations. However, the specification does specify exact matches, in some cases, for images produced by the same implementation. [...]"